# Nesting add_rewrite_rule() with custom page and subcategories

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

The url structure looking for is :

- blog/category/subcategory/
- blog/category/post/
- blog/category/subcategory/post/

My rewrite rules :

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Sure with such rewrite_rule the post will response
blog/category/post/

But sure, blog/category/subcategory/ it returns a 404 page error.

Tried to use as array for the $query

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
array(
        'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
 'index.php?$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]',

),
        'top'
    );
```

But it did not work since it matches the first from the array.

Any advice.

Comment: did you flush permalinks and what do rewrite checker/tester plugins say when you put the URL in? Where is this code located? Can you edit it so that we see the entire code  in the order it appears rather than snippets of a single rule?

Comment: Yes sure @TomJNowell, i am using flush_rewrite_rules(); after this function. i see that Wordpress use Query Vars to indicate  type in the rules such as @ name or @ category_name etc... and using init action early to check whether it's single or archive and i can't find universal Query Vars that will work in the fly and indicate depend on the slug. yes the solution sounds weak because there could be slug duplication in the DB but better than nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand most of your comment, query vars are just query vars, there's no distinction between universal or non-universal that makes no sense. I noticed you did not edit your question or answer any of the questions I asked :(

Comment: Yes sure @TomJNowell, i am using flush_rewrite_rules(); after this function.  means i did flush my permalinks, you mean Query Vars it's not important for the rewrite rules ??

Comment: query variables are important but that's not what I was trying to say, did you try a rewrite rule tester plugin like I asked? I also asked if you could edit your question to include all of the code, you mentioned 3 rewrite rules but there is only code for 1 in your question! The order and how the other rules are written is important but it's missing from your question